# What JS event fired on input field when iOS 8 "Scan credit card" feature is used?

Tags: javascript, safari, ios8

I'm wondering is there any JS event triggered on input field when I'm scanning my credit card? Currently I tried `keyup, change, paste` but none of them were fired. And no information found in Google about that. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, Safari iOS < 8.3 does not trigger any JS event on card scanning, so my bindings do not work on exp. month and year fields (`<select>` elements).

On iOS 8.3 and 8.4 devices my bindings do work, so I guess that `change` event gets triggered.